# typescript: How to import with original names

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have a module

```
module A 
{
    export function X ()
    {
        …
    }
}
```

which I want to use in another module like this:

```
// Import fails with "Cannot find module 'A'." even with
// A.ts being in same directory
import * as A from "A";

module B
{
    function Y ()
    {
        // Module and function name carry information
        // which I want to keep for readability.
        A.X ();
    }
}
```

This should be the easiest case of export and import but I just can't get it to work.

**UPDATE:**

As I said: The module name carries value. Having similar named functions in multiple modules (or namespaces) will happen. i.E.

```
module C 
{
    export function X ()
    {
        …
    }
}
```

And I certainly don't want to do name the functions `A.A_X` and `C.C_X` — Redundant naming makes me cringe.

Comment: The module name is the name of the file. Your example using a wildcard import is why the same function name in multiple files doesn't have to result in a conflict. Even if you had the same file name with the same functions in two different places you could import both using wildcard with different names, ex ```import * as A from "./A"; 
import * as OtherA from "../A"; 
``` Or you could import the functions themself with `as` like `import {func as func1} from "./A"; import {func as func2} from "./B"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use a module

Do not use the keyword `module`. It has been renamed to [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) and it is not useful to make modules.

```
// A.ts
export function X()
{
    …
}

// B.ts
import * as A from "./A";
function Y ()
{
    A.X ();
}
```

A module is a JavaScript (or TypeScript) file with an `import` or an `export` at the root level.

## A TS namespace in a module

If you want to export a `namespace` from your module, here is an example:

```
// A.ts
export namespace A {
    export function X ()
    {
        …
    }
}

// B.ts
import {A} from "./A";
function Y () {
    A.X ();
}
```

In file `A.ts`, notice the two exports. At the root level, it is the standard module export. In the namespace, the `export function X` is a non-standard feature of TypeScript used to declare something public in the namespace.

Additionally, notice the syntax change of import in file `B.ts`.

You can read a presentation of the module syntax in [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) from Mozilla.

Comment: If I don't use `namespace` as you suggest then on then javascript side a function just called `function X()` is generated. Of course I want that the generated javascript function is also called `function A.X()`.  (Otherwise I will soon have several conflicting init () and onXXXClick functions)
Which is the case when I use `namespace A`. However then I get an error "error TS2306: File '…/A.ts' is not a module."

This seems so complicated.

Comment: @Martin The current generated JavaScript is not so important. In a couple of years, the generated JS will have the `export` and `import` keywords and your named `A` import. But I'll edit to add namespaces in your module.